# How can I permanently disable bluetooth on a HP ProBook 4530S?

Tags: bios, bluetooth

Is there any way I can disable bluetooth in the BIOS of a HP ProBook 4530S? I want to permanently remove bluetooth from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really "permanently remove" bluetooth from the system because it is actually just a piece of hardware.

The closes to this you can do is to disable access to it for anyone using the system:

In your BIOS there should be an option to set the wireless-antennae status. Find the bluetooth adapter section and disable it.

Now, head to the security menu in  your BIOS, and add a password; thus making it imposible for users to re-enable the adapter.

Of course, you could also open up the laptop and remove the bluetooth adapter alltogether, but that would require some technical prowess.

Answer (score -1):

You can't really do that without a screwdriver, but if all you want is to shut it off permanently, go into device manager (type it into the search in the start menu), go to network devices, find bluetooth, and disable it. If you want pictures, or more info, your OS could help.

Comment: re-enables at reboot

Answer (score -1):

Must be run with root privileges:

defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ControllerPowerState 0
Turns OFF bluetooth

defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ControllerPowerState 1
Turns on bluetooth

Comment: The OP is not using a Mac.